# Simple way to get all .o files but one

Tags: command-line, gcc, regex

I'm trying to link all *.o files from another folder and would like to in my Makefile do something like;

```
g++ *.o (folder/*.o and not folder/main.o) -o bin
```

Is there someway I can use somekind of simple regex here?

Comment: It can be done using Makefile. I am not pretty good in makefile. So learn it.

Comment: I'm already using it in a Makefile but I would like for the makefile to be independent of whats in "folder"

Comment: remove folder/main.o before linking? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `g++ *.o $( echo folder/*.o |tr ' ' "\n" | egrep -v folder/main.o )`, assuming none of `folder/*.o` have SPACES in their names.

Here's how it works:

`echo folder/*.o` produces a space-separated list of the filenames, with the directory.
`tr ' ' "\n"` changes all the spaces to newlines (giving us one filename per line, which makes `egrep` happy.
`egrep -v folder/main.o` eliminates the undesired filename from this list.
`$()` puts the rest of the filenames on the command line. Since `$IFS` defaults to SPACE, TAB, NEWLINE, we don't have to `tr` them back to spaces.

Comment: It works great now thanks :D Although I had to put the command within ` ` instead of $( ) since it returned nothing for some reason. Thanks again :D

Comment: Perhaps you can replace for `g++ *.o $( ls folder/*.o | egrep -v main.o )` for ls separates each item with a newline already.

Answer (score 1):

You should use makefiles, or even better autotools, but you can do something like this:

```
ls folder/ | grep "*.o" | grep -v "main.o" | while read -r file; do g++ $file -o bin; done
```

This question would be better answered in a bash related stack site anyway haha.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm n00b on stacksites, just wondering which of them would that be, the "bash related" site?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ls -1 folder/*.o | grep -v main.o | xargs -I{} g++ {} -o bin
```

Explanation:

- ls -1 folder/*.o -> list all .o files (one per line) in folder folder
- grep -v main.o -> exclude main.o from the list
- xargs -I{} g++ {} -o bin -> execute "**g++ file -o bin**"